# Send commands from terminal to Java swing app

Tags: java, terminal, process, signals

I have a working java app and now I would like to extend it to be controlled over ssh. Let's say I have a swing button that increases a counter. I would like to be able to ssh in that computer and say something `$: myapp increase` and have the button's action listener executed.

Maybe I'm using the wrong keywords but I could not find a solution. The 'kinda' solution I could think of is using signals but I'm not even sure if they can be used as I am used to from C and if that can be done without knowing the actual process ID.

Any material that can get me started would be welcome.

Comment: what about exposing and accessing a rest service [via ssh](https://www.booleanworld.com/guide-ssh-port-forwarding-tunnelling/)? Or add an web socket based tcp/ip server to the app to communicate with? You can also send arbitrary stuff to the stdin channel of [a running process](https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi) (on linux), you'd need a thread in the swing app polling stdin.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a lightweight message broker to send commands. It might be a little heavier than writing out a TCP/IP or HTTP service. But it also might be a little easier to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

signals are hard to read from java, because there is a lot of difference between OSes on how to do those (some don't even have the concept), and java is designed to expose anything that can be generalized across all OSes java runs on, and to not expose anything that might not be there.

The usual way to do it, is via TCP/IP (so, `java.net.Socket`), or HTTP (so, `jetty` or some such).

Note that webapps can trivially be accessed remotely and can be scripted fairly easily. You could also consider building a command line / terminal based app, for example with [lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) which you can shove into a terminal session keeper / eternal SSH kinda deal.